# Shiny App: Scatterplot reactive to multiple inputs

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to make a shiny app that allows the user to select a group (`cut`) and a variable (i.e., `depth`,`table`, or `price`) for both the x and y-axes of a scatterplot. The UI code below works well for allowing the user to make the selections however, I am having trouble with the server. I think the issue is with filtering the UI selections into two data frames and then using `rbind()` to combine them but I don't know another way to proceed.

How can I make `ggplot()` reactive to the two choices that users have for the x and y-axes?

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- diamonds %>%
  select(cut,depth,table,price) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c('depth','table','price'),
               names_to = 'Variable',
               values_to = 'Value')

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("x_cut", "X-axis Cut", choices = unique(dat$cut)),
  selectInput("x_variable", "X-axis Variable", choices = unique(dat$Variable)),
  selectInput("y_cut", "Y-axis Cut", choices = unique(dat$cut)),
  selectInput("y_variable", "Y-axis Variable", choices = unique(dat$Variable)),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    filtered_xdat <- dat %>%
      filter(cut == input$x_cut, Variable == input$x_variable)
    
    filtered_ydat <- dat %>%
      filter(cut == input$y_cut, Variable == input$y_variable)
    
    filtered_dat <- rbind(filtered_xdat, filtered_ydat)
      
    filtered_dat %>%
      ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(x = input$x_variable,
                     y = input$y_variable)) +
      geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

# Warning: Error in geom_point: Problem while setting up geom.
# ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
# Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
#   ! `geom_point()` requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
```

I have tried this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    filtered_xdat <- dat %>%
      filter(cut == input$x_cut,
             xVariable == input$x_variable) %>%
      as.data.frame()

    filtered_ydat <- dat %>%
      filter(cut == input$y_cut,
             yVariable == input$y_variable) %>%
      as.data.frame()

    ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(x = filtered_xdat$xVariable, y = filtered_ydat$yVariable)) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
}

# Warning: Error in filter: ℹ In argument: `xVariable == input$x_variable`.
# Caused by error:
#   ! object 'xVariable' not found
```

and this as well:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    filtered_dat <- dat %>%
      filter(cut %in% c(input$x_cut, input$y_cut),
             Variable %in% c(input$x_variable, input$y_variable))
    
    ggplot(data = filtered_dat, aes(x = !!sym(input$x_variable), y = !!sym(input$y_variable))) +
      geom_point() +
      theme_minimal()
  })
}

# Warning: Error in geom_point: Problem while computing aesthetics.
# ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
# Caused by error in `FUN()`:
#   ! object 'depth' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

`rbind` may not be the best option here.  While `cbind` should normally work, in your example there is no relationship between x and y variables. So, I just cbind with a new function `cbindPad`, allowing for different number of rows.  In your real use case, you may just need to use `cbind`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

#########   cbind datasets with different number of rows  ######
cbindPad <- function(...){
  args <- list(...)
  n <- sapply(args,nrow)
  mx <- max(n)
  pad <- function(x, mx){
    if (nrow(x) < mx){
      nms <- colnames(x)
      padTemp <- matrix(NA, mx - nrow(x), ncol(x))
      colnames(padTemp) <- nms
      if (ncol(x)==0) {
        return(padTemp)
      } else {
        return(rbind(x,padTemp))
      }
    }
    else{
      return(x)
    }
  }
  rs <- lapply(args,pad,mx)
  return(do.call(cbind,rs))
}

dat <- diamonds %>%
  select(cut,depth,table,price) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c('depth','table','price'),
               names_to = 'Variable',
               values_to = 'Value')

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("x_cut", "X-axis Cut", choices = unique(dat$cut)),
  selectInput("x_variable", "X-axis Variable", choices = unique(dat$Variable)),
  selectInput("y_cut", "Y-axis Cut", choices = unique(dat$cut)),
  selectInput("y_variable", "Y-axis Variable", choices = unique(dat$Variable)),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    filtered_xdat <- dat %>%
      filter(cut == input$x_cut, Variable == input$x_variable) %>% 
      rename(cutx=cut, Variablex=Variable, Valuex = Value)
    
    filtered_ydat <- dat %>%
      filter(cut == input$y_cut, Variable == input$y_variable)
    
    filtered_dat <- cbindPad(filtered_xdat, filtered_ydat) 
    
    filtered_dat %>% 
      ggplot() +
      geom_point(aes(x = Valuex,
                     y = Value )) #  +
     # geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```